# Change text of an android message

Tags: android, python, sl4a, qpython, qpython3

Recently I made a challenge for myself: make a clock using qpython3 on my android. The script was working fine when I "told" it to print the current time every second, however when I "told" it to make a notification, a lot of different notifications were popping up every second.
I am using the following code to make notifications pop up:

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
droid.notify("a", "b")
```

I want one out of the three following possibilities to solve my problem:

- Make the notification disappear
- Make the notification appear for a determined amount of time
- Change notification text and then update it

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius) and write a Java Script for doing what you want.
I dont think the androidhelper API can do this for you.